# Can Index Sorting improve the performance of the sorting in the table?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with 0.5M of records. In my UI I want to show this data within a table paginated.

```
+---+---+---+---+
| A | B | C | D |
+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |
```

The user can sort, for example, A, C, and D columns (asc/desc). Not in conjunction, but by any of these 3 columns separately.

From what I can see the [Index Sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/index-modules-index-sorting.html) allows to order the data in each segment for the specified set of columns.

From my understanding, I can specify a sorting setting for the index to store column A sorted and this should make the sorting exactly by this field faster. Or I can specify A + C, and exactly A in conjunction with C should be faster.

Can I benefit from Index Sorting in my scenario? Or simply rely on ES default configuration?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create another index with a similar `data-set and try it out .. Use [Reindex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) API for the same. By this, you can see for yourself if it improves the performance or not.
2. Do you even need the optimization considering there is an over-head of the same at the index time ?